# Collation issue while join query in MVC5 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, collation

When I join two tables I got a collation issue that is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

Then I set the collation in my db using the following code

```
ALTER DATABASE [CAM] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;

ALTER TABLE CAM_Users 
    ALTER COLUMN [EmployeeCode] VARCHAR(50)
        COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL;
```

But I still get the same error.

My join query is this:

```
List<DTOUserManagement> users = (from CAMuser in _unitOfWorkAsync.RepositoryAsync<CAM_Users>().Queryable()
                                 join QRuser in _unitOfWorkAsync.RepositoryAsync<CAM_V_EmployeeMaster>().Queryable() on CAMuser.EmployeeCode equals QRuser.EmployeeCode into t
                                 from t1 in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 join CAMDomain in _unitOfWorkAsync.RepositoryAsync<CAM_Domain>().Queryable() on CAMuser.DomainID equals CAMDomain.DomainID into t2
                                 from t3 in t2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 where CAMuser.IsActive
                                 select new DTOUserManagement
                                               {
                                                   TransactUserCode = CAMuser.TransactUserCode,
                                                   EmployeeCode = CAMuser.EmployeeCode,
                                                   EmployeeName = t1.EmployeeName,
                                                   Email = t1.EMail,
                                                   DomainID = CAMuser.DomainID,
                                                   DomainName = t3.DomainName,
                                                   IsActive = CAMuser.IsActive,
                                                   AssignedRole = CAMuser.AssignedRoles
                                               }).ToList();
```

How can I solve this?

Please reply anybody

Comment: try using COLLATE in  join clause

Comment: What's the collation of `CAM_V_EmployeeMaster.EmployeeCode`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the [COLLATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) must match on joining columns.

There are two ways to fix this.  First you could change the collation on each column.  Or second, you can change the collation at execution time.  Here's an example of the second approach:

Sample Data

```
/* T1 and T2 are identical tables in structre and content, except 
 * for the collation.
 */
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
    (
        ID        VARCHAR(3)    COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    )
;

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
    (
        ID        VARCHAR(3)    COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
    )
;

INSERT INTO @T1
    (
        ID
    )
VALUES
    ('x'),
    ('y'),
    ('z')
;

INSERT INTO @T2
    (
        ID
    )
VALUES
    ('x'),
    ('y'),
    ('z')
;
```

Anti Pattern - Will not Work

```
/* This query will failed with the error:
 * Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
 */
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @T1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN @T2 AS t2        ON t1.ID = t2.ID
;
```

Corrected - No Error

```
/* Success.
 */
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @T1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN @T2 AS t2        ON t1.ID = t2.ID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
;
```

Comment: I am using entity framework for select data that is given in the question.How can use the above code in my query

Comment: Sorry you did make it clear this was an EF problem.  I don't think you can directly solve this issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631035/how-to-resolve-collation-conflicts-with-the-entity-framework and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702119/linq-request-with-2-related-entities).  You could create a new view as an intermediate object.

Comment: I take it using just one collation throughout the db is not an option here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your tables that are involved in these JOINs here to verify that **all** columns involved have the same collation.

You can do this with this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.name, 
    Collation = c.collation_name
FROM 
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE 
    t.name IN ('CAM_Users', 'CAM_Domain')  -- add any further tables to check
    AND ty.name IN ('char', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'varchar')
ORDER BY
    t.name, c.name
```

If there are columns that **do not** match the database default collation, you need to change those to be the same as all other columns. Once **all** the string columns in those tables are the same collation, then your joins should work.

**Update:** use this query to find those tables & columns that do not have the current default database collation:

```
SELECT
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.name, 
    Collation = c.collation_name
FROM 
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE 
    ty.name IN ('char', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'varchar')
    AND c.collation_name <> 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
ORDER BY
    t.name, c.name
```

Comment: While I run the above code I got the collation as **Latin1_General_CI_AI**

Comment: I set the collation as **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** for each column.But getting the collation of that fields are **Latin1_General_CI_AI**

Comment: @Safeena: did you set the collation for **each column** involved explicitly? Setting the **database collation** does **NOT** change all columns! You have to **explicitly set it** for each and every single column, one by one

Comment: yes,I set collation of each column like 
`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CAM_Domain] ALTER COLUMN [Description]
            varchar(100) 
   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL;`

Comment: @Safeena: well, in that case - there must be additional tables involved in your JOINs somehow - check those! I added a second query to find those columns that are **not** the database default collation - does that give you any more "problematic" columns?=

Comment: The 2nd code return my column collation which is not  set.
Actually the collation set but after set primary key.the collation changed to old collation

Comment: Hi,I fix my issue.First remove the primary key then set collation.Then set primary key again.Then Restart my PC